# Is it possible to have a Kafka cluster out of different EC2 machines?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, cluster-computing

I am working on some benchmarking tests for Kafka and wanted to try setting up a cluster composed by 3 different EC2 instances from different Regions (US/Europe/Asia) but since those machines are not part of a same LAN, im not sure if kafka supports this kind of clustering.

Is it possible to setup this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> different EC2 instances

Kafka doesn't care about heterogenous instance types, although I'm not sure why you'd want to do this since you'd ideally want to be using some configuration management software like Cloudformation or Terraform which would make you select one instance type

> from different Regions (US/Europe/Asia)

One cluster across different regions will not work without considerable lag and inconsistent connections/timeouts. Specifically, Zookeeper requires subsecond connections

Instead, you can make individual clusters per region, then use tools like MirrorMaker2 to replicate topics across regions. There's also a Confluent-specific solution called Cluster Linking